# How to return only value in pie on apexcharts.js won't convert percent

Tags: pie-chart, apex, apexcharts

I'm developing a website for a society and I am using `apexCharts.js`, I want to show a simple pie chart but when I display this, the value on dataLabel is a percent.
I don't want to convert them into values, of course the true value is display when we hover the pie chart.

I have already read the [documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/pie-donut/) and searched on datalabels options. The way I think is:

```
formatter: function(val) { return val }
```

but it does not work...
So I did not find an example neither on github nor here solving the issue.

Below my script :

```
var options = {
  chart: {
    width: 650,
    type: 'pie',
  },
  labels: ['Date formation',
    'Date formation 1',
    'Date formation 2',
    'Date formation 3',
    'Nombre de jours restant ',
    'Nombre de formations restantes'
  ],
  series: [202, 80, 62, 250, 52, 30],
  /* this portion NEED custom ???? */
  formatter: function (val) {
    return val
  },
  title: {
    text: "Jours de formation produits ou plannifiés"
  },
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 480,
    options: {
      chart: {
        width: 200
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'center'
      }
    }
  }]
}
var chart = new ApexCharts(
  document.querySelector("#chart"),
  options);
chart.render();
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The formatter property needs to be nested inside `dataLabels` property. Like this:

```js
    var options = {
      chart: {
        width: 650,
        type: 'pie',
      },
      labels: ['Date formation',
        'Date formation 1',
        'Date formation 2',
        'Date formation 3',
        'Nombre de jours restant ',
        'Nombre de formations restantes'
      ],
      series: [202, 80, 62, 250, 52, 30],
      dataLabels: {
        formatter: function (val, opts) {
            return opts.w.config.series[opts.seriesIndex]
        },
      },
    }

    var chart = new ApexCharts(
      document.querySelector("#chart"),
      options);
    chart.render();
```

You will be able to get the default values of the series in the 2nd param (opts) of `formatter` function. You can use that param and get the original value instead of percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple here is the code-->

```
            options={{
              dataLabels: {
                formatter: function (val) {
                  const percent = (val/1);
                  return percent.toFixed(0)
                },
              },
```

Comment: This is wrong. The value val which is passed is already the percentage (just without the %).

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add to @junedchhipa 's answer that if you want to display both the raw value and the percentage you can try :

```
  dataLabels: {
    formatter: function (val, opts) {
        return [opts.w.config.series[opts.seriesIndex],val+'%']
    },
  },
```